# complete unload external swf and sound

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using this code for load and unload an external swf for a button. when I click on button, swf loads and when again I click on button swf unloads, but sound still exist and just swf screen disappeares.

Please correct this code, I want swf to completetely unload.

```
printer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF);

var fl_Loader:Loader;

//This variable keeps track of whether you want to load or unload the SWF
var fl_ToLoad:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToLoad)
    {
        fl_Loader = new Loader();
        addChild(fl_Loader);
        fl_Loader.load(new URLRequest("quiz.swf"));


printer.x=100;
printer.y=100;
    }
    else

    {       fl_Loader.unloadAndStop();

        removeChild(fl_Loader);
        fl_Loader = null;

printer.x=155;
printer.y=334;
    }
    // Toggle whether you want to load or unload the SWF
    fl_ToLoad = !fl_ToLoad;
}
```

Comment: Try calling `fl_Loader.haltSPP();` right before you unload it.

Comment: please tell i must add this code to which one line? because i add `fl_Loader.haltSPP(); fl_Loader.unloadAndStop();` but gets error

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the code in loaded swf than you may add `Event.UNLOAD` listener. In the event handler you can do some cleaning:

- stop all sounds,
- stop videos,
- remove event listeners (specially these attached to the `Stage`)

This way, the unloading should be smooth and easy.